# How do I convert this CURL request to a normal HTTP request Javascript

Tags: javascript, curl, nlp, ibm-watson

I want to use this code snippet that I got from the IBM Natural Language API but run it in Javascript. How do I go about converting this to be a normal HTTP POST request? Just some pointers on rearranging the syntax would be amazing, I know there are a few placeholders here in the code that I'll change for what I need.

```
$ curl -X POST -u "apikey:{apikey}" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{
  "text": "I love apples! I do not like oranges.",
  "features": {
    "sentiment": {
      "targets": [
        "apples",
        "oranges",
        "broccoli"
      ]
    },
    "keywords": {
      "emotion": true
    }
  }
}' \
"{url}/v1/analyze?version=2019-07-12"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to clarify what you mean by javascript. If it is node.js then you can use the ibm-watson sdk - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/natural-language-understanding?code=node#analyze.

There is sample code at the link to show you how.

```js
const NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1 = require('ibm-watson/natural-language-understanding/v1');
const { IamAuthenticator } = require('ibm-watson/auth');

const naturalLanguageUnderstanding = new NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1({
  version: '2020-08-01',
  authenticator: new IamAuthenticator({
    apikey: '{apikey}',
  }),
  serviceUrl: '{url}',
});

const analyzeParams = {
  'text': 'I love apples! I do not like oranges.',
  'features': {
    "sentiment": {
      "targets": [
        "apples",
        "oranges",
        "broccoli"
      ]
    },
    'keywords': {
      'emotion': true
    }
  }
};

naturalLanguageUnderstanding.analyze(analyzeParams)
  .then(analysisResults => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(analysisResults, null, 2));
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('error:', err);
  });
```

If you are referring to javascript inside a browser, then what you use really depends on the javascript framework that you are using. This would be `xhttp` for raw javascript, but most frameworks simplify the process for you.

An alternative would be to use the ibm-watson sdk through browserify - https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/tree/master/examples/browserify

or web pack - https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/tree/master/examples/webpack